# sending textfield values to servlet on selecting a checkbox

Tags: servlets, checkbox

I'm developing a jsp/serlvet application. I have a page with a list of checkboxes and textfields . I want to send values of selected checkbox that is  corresponding textbox value to a servlet . In the servlet , I want to extract these values and use them .

Comment: did you at least try to find any tutorial on how servlets work? its very basic. SO is not for writing your programs!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info